# How to get current workspace path in Xcode source editor extension?

Tags: swift, xcode, xcode-extension

I am trying to get current workspace path through Xcode source editor extension but I'm unable to find any help.

Comment: To my understanding (I read [this tutorial](https://nshipster.com/xcode-source-extensions/)) a source editor extension does nothing more than editing a file. What has this to do with the workspace path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not supported in Xcode Extensions.